# Was 1965's Doctor Zhivago in cinemas for years?

Tags: doctor-zhivago

The authors of [Taschen's 100 All-Time Favorite Movies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3836524007) claim that, with respect to the classic [Doctor Zhivago](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1006037_doctor_zhivago),

> Eager moviegoers stood in lines that wrapped around blocks to get a glimpse of soviet snuggling, and some theaters ran the film for years on end.

I can't find any on-line source to corroborate this. Did cinemas really run the movie for years?

Comment: It is entirely possible, but considering you're talking about the 1960s, chances are small that such information is available online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Possibly

Certainly there is some evidence/corroboration that the movie ran in some theaters for periods of a year or more and so the quote by the authors may be taken at face value

> The screening recalled the glory days of the 1960s Hollywood epic, when films were presented like plays, with reserved seats. The movies were always preceded by an overture and included a perfectly placed break for an intermission. **“Doctor Zhivago” played in exclusive runs in major cities that lasted a year or more.** The huge downtown theaters that booked the film only showed it once or twice a day.
>
> <sup>[Source](https://www.ctpost.com/living/article/Hearst-movie-club-sees-1965-classic-Doctor-12720587.php)</sup>